# How to custom specified CalendarView item's foreground in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm developing a UWP APP with a `CalendarView` and I want to mark some special days on it.

By using `CalendarViewDayItemChanging` event I accessed the `CalendarViewDayItem`, and set its `background` with a special color successfully. But when I set the `foreground` as well I found the number on Calendarview didn't change.

How could I get the result I want ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow.

What you're going to want to do is called "Retemplate" your control.

[You can read about templating here](http://www.wpftutorial.net/templates.html)

Once you understand what that is you will want to get the CalendarView style from MSDN, copy it into your control template, and modify the values that you wish to change. You can even change the entire look and feel of the control if you wish from this point.

You can find the [MSDN documentation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299113.aspx)

A little easier method to accomplish this but a litte more hacky is to just find the property you want to change and use a style and setter to change it.

```
<Page 
     ....>

<Page.Resources>
     <Style TargetType="CalendarView">
        <Setter Property="CalendarItemForeground" Value="WhatEverColorYouWant"/>
     </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

Comment: You got me ! I'm still a novice here. Thank sooo much for your guide. I will try to understand the "Retemplate".

Comment: @Plex if this works for you please don't forget to checkmark and upvote the answer so others know

Comment: @ Anthony Russell  I think I'm very close to the success. I've created a custom template which `TargetType` is `CalendarViewDayItem` in xaml. Then applied it to specified `CalendarViewDayItem` in code. But I got a exception during dubgging. Do I made it clear?  Is there anyway to provide more info to you?

Comment: @Plex I can't debug from a comment. That sounds more like a separate question. This question specifically asked about how to style the CalendarItemForeground. We don't want to stack questions because then it makes it more difficult for people with similar issues to find answers

Comment: @ Anthony Russell That makes great sense. I will try to solve the new problem. Thank you anyway.